# Setting primefaces calendar end date after setting start date

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, calendar, mindate

I'm using primefaces calendar for the creation of an event. With the "mindate" parameter i have disabled the days before the current day. I want to do this even with the end date, disabling the days before the start date. I don't know how to handle this, since the backing bean gets the start date only after the validation of the entire form.

I need the backing bean to be set right after entering the start date on the inputText field.

Here the HTML:

```
<p:calendar immediate="true" mindate="#{createEventBean.today}" id="startingtime" value="#{createEventBean.current.startingtime}"/>

<p:calendar mindate="#{createEventBean.current.startingtime}" id="endingtime" value="#{createEventBean.current.endingtime}"/>
```

here the backing bean's method:

```
public Date getToday(){
    return new Date();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `<p:ajax>` to update the end date on select of start date. The `<p:calendar>` supports the ajax event `dateSelect` which is fired when a date is selected.

So, this should do:

```
<p:calendar value="#{bean.startDate}" mindate="#{bean.today}">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="endDate" />
</p:calendar>
<p:calendar id="endDate" value="#{bean.endDate}" mindate="#{bean.startDate}" />
```

Comment: What if user change date from keyboard manually. Is it also check this case?

Comment: @Furkan: if the value was changed manually then you can use event `blur` the same way as done for `dateSelect`. `<p:ajax event="blur" update="endDate" />`.